# Attach CSV to E-Mail with MIMEBase, only attaches 'bin' document

Tags: python, csv, email, mime-mail

I want to write a function to attach a csv file to an E-Mail with HTML text. Everything works fine. I sends the E-Mail with the text and the attachment with the right information. Only the data format is wrong. I tried different varieties in `MIMEBASE('application', 'octet-stream')`. This one gives me a **'.bin'** data which I cannot open on macOS. Others gave me a plain text data which included the right data, but I don't wanna copy it manually into a csv. Does someone have a solution how I get out the data as **'.csv'**? Most of the solutions I found here just looked like my code below.

Code:

```
def send_mail(receiver, subject, filepath, attachname):
    
    #login information
    port = 123
    smtp_server = "test.server.com"
    login = "testlogin" # your login 
    password = "12345678910" # your password 

    # specify the sender’s and receiver’s email addresses and text in HTML
    sender = "testmail@test.com"
    receiver = receiver
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message["Subject"] = subject
    message["From"] = sender
    message["To"] = COMMASPACE.join([receiver])
    html_text = """\
    <html>
      <body>
        <p>Hi ,<br>
        <p>kind regards</p>
        <p> This is an automatized Mail </p>
      </body>
    </html>
    """
    # convert both parts to MIMEText objects and add them to the MIMEMultipart message
    text = MIMEText(html_text, "html")
    message.attach(text)
    
    #add a file as attachment
    file = open(filepath, "rb")
    att = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    att.set_payload(file.read())
    encoders.encode_base64(att)
    att.add_header("Content_Disposition",
                    'attachment', filename = attachname)
    message.attach(att)
    try:
        #send your message with credentials specified above
        with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
            server.connect(smtp_server, port)
            server.ehlo()
            server.starttls()
            server.ehlo()
            server.login(login, password)
            server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message.as_string())

        # tell the script to report if your message was sent or which errors need to be fixed 
        print('Sent')
    except (gaierror, ConnectionRefusedError):
        print('Failed to connect to the server. Bad connection settings?')
    except smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected:
        print('Failed to connect to the server. Wrong user/password?')
    except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
        print('SMTP error occurred: ' + str(e))

send_mail('testmail@test.com', 'TEST', '/Users/Changer/Desktop/test.csv', 'test.csv')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email clients may use the content type of the attachment part to determine which program is used to open the attachment, so specifying a suitable content type may help.

This code uses the standard library's mimetypes module to try to guess the correct content type of the attachment, based on its name:

```
import mimetypes

mimetypes.init()

def send_mail(receiver, subject, filepath, attachname):
    ...

    mimetype, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(attachname)
    if mimetype is None:
        mimetype = 'application/octet-stream'
    type_, _, subtype = mimetype.partition('/')
    att = MIMEBase(type_, subtype)
    ...
```

The above code will generate these headers for the attachment:

```
b'Content-Type: text/x-comma-separated-values'
b'MIME-Version: 1.0'
b'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'
b'Content_Disposition: attachment; filename="test.csv"'
```

Whether a mac will open a csv with a spreadsheet application (I assume this is what you want) depends on the configuration of the machine  (See [this blog](https://www.resrequest.com/blog/how-to-open-csv-files-with-excel-by-default/) for an example).  If you want to be sure open the file in a spreadsheet it might be more effective to convert it to a spreadsheet format and send the spreadsheet.